# Hacking the memory of another library

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to launch or access a minesweeper instance to hook and call it's functions on demand to play a bit and to create a solver. I've tried two ways: launching a process with it, and injecting a dll of mine in it with a method found online. Both ended up in the same problem: I get error 998 when I access the memory of the library of minesweeper from my program or my injected library. What do you recommend me to do? I don't know much of the Windows API so I don't know if the problem is on the methods I'm using or if I have to do some extra function calling or changing some settings.

Comment: If your goal is to simulate Minesweeper, then it's best to write your own Minesweeper-like game model.

Comment: My goal is to trigger minesweeper functions and hook them. I don't have problems with that since I already did it but with libraries that reside in my memory space (don't know the correct way of saying it). What I mean is: i don't have problems with the part of the hacking, just with the part of the memory permissions. The rest is easy for me.

Comment: What code have you written that doesn't work?

Comment: No way anyone can answer well with such sparse information. If you want to call functions then you will need to be in process. But how do you suppose those function calls can be invoked? It's not your process. You are not in charge.

Comment: My DLLMain get's invoked. Please check the pastebin I posted for my dll. in response to Mike Kwan

Comment: You should paste your code directly in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you are trying to write to the memory of the target without changing the page protection. Executable pages are typically read-only (and executable). You need to use [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change this protection. Usually, this sort of code would be executed:

```
DWORD flOldProtect;

VirtualProtect((LPVOID)from, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &flOldProtect);
...
VirtualProtect((LPVOID)from, 5, flOldProtect, &flOldProtect);
```

This code changes the protection so you can write to it. You would perform your hooking code, etc. within `...` and then restore the page protection. [Here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mk08/Example%20C%20Trainer/src/) is a really basic trainer I wrote for someone a while ago which works via DLL injection.

Comment: :D unfortunately I get those errors when calling VirtualProtect (or just by accessing the memory).

Comment: Btw it might be helpful for you to know that Minesweeper keeps a byte array in memory of where the mines are. This means you can read it directly and know which cells contain the bombs as soon as your DLL is injected.

Comment: Mike Kwawn, http://pastebin.com/y4gktDVA. That displays "return 0 error code 998". Note: the dll is compiled as 64 bit.

Comment: Where you have specified `oldProtection` in your call to `VirtualProtect` should be `&oldProtection`. Also you really should not be performing your work in the `DllMain`, since that should return straight away. The common practice (even though it's technically looked down upon) is to create a thread at `DllMain`. The **proper** way is to export an `init` function from your DLL which is invoked by the injector.

Comment: It's a PDWORD not a DWORD. But that hardly would be the problem.

Comment: I also thought of that and create a thtread that I made to sleep during some seconds and the same happened.

Comment: It is a problem. The API takes `oldProtection` and treats it as a pointer and tries to write a value there. Since you assigned `NULL` to it, it attempts to write to address 0. As a separate issue, I believe a JMP is not 5 bytes on x86-64.

Comment: oh sorry. Im gonna try again with it fixed. About the 5 bytes of jmp thanks for the warning, it's my first time for 64

Comment: Your `loaded` boolean is unnecessary by the way. You should be doing a switch/case on `ul_reason_for_call`, checking for `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`

Comment: I think I'm ok now it worked if i didn't cast to long. Many thanks, owe you one

Comment: @Mike Depends on the JMP. If you use the same one as you did in x86, relative address which is the most common, then yes it is 5 bytes still on x64.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the problem with that is that it only has a range of 2GB. You can't guarantee that the delta of the target address to the detour function is within that range. I believe on x64, the common way is to do `mov rax, ABSOLUTE_ADDRESS` then `jmp rax` which requires 12 bytes. Other ways of guaranteeing the distance also take more than 5 bytes.

Comment: @MikeKwan True. In my case I've only ever done this kind of thing when the target is in the same module as the code being modified. In which case it is fine.